# SQL query - selecting the columns whose grand total is greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my SQL query:

```
DROP TABLE #tempi
CREATE TABLE #tempi
             (
                          nav1 VARCHAR(50),
                          nav2 INT        ,
                          nav3 INT        ,
                          nav4 INT        ,
                          nav5 INT
             )
INSERT
INTO   #tempi
SELECT   COALESCE(CAST(machinename AS VARCHAR(28)), 'Grand Total:')               AS machinename        ,
         SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '1001' THEN DATEDIFF(mi, 0, total_time) END) AS crate_small        ,
         SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '1002' THEN DATEDIFF(mi, 0, total_time) END) AS crate_medium       ,
         SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '1014' THEN DATEDIFF(mi, 0, total_time) END) AS front_air_deflector,
         SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '9999' THEN DATEDIFF(mi, 0, total_time) END) AS no_schedule
FROM     ven_fullreportmaster vfrm
         INNER JOIN ven_descriptionmaster vdm
         ON       vdm.description_id = vfrm..description_id
         INNER JOIN ven_machinemaster vm
         ON       vm.machine_id = vfrm..machine_id
WHERE    vfrm.entry_date        = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE()-7, 105)
         --and  vfrm.shift_id =1
AND      vfrm.is_task_completed = 'Y'
GROUP BY machinename WITH ROLLUP
```

The output in `tempi` table:

```
nav1    nav2    nav3   nav4   nav5

abc      0:0     0:0     0:0   1:0

def      0:0     1:0     2:0   1:0

ghi      0:0     0:0     0:0   1:0

grand    0:0     1:0     2:0   3:0
 total
```

I want to select the columns whose grand total is greater than 0. How to achieve it?

Comment: To dynamically change the column list requires dynamic SQL. What should happen if there are no such columns with a grand total > 0?

Comment: there are around 40 job columns.. and 15 machines (row) ..so atleast one column will be greater than 0..there is no chance of all columns to be zero :)

Comment: plz help me out to write a dynamic query for it..i desperatly searchng for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tempi ( nav1 VARCHAR(50), nav2 INT, nav3 INT, nav4 INT, nav5 INT ) 
INSERT INTO #tempi VALUES('Grand Total:',    0.0,     1.0,     2.0,   3.0) 

DECLARE @dynsql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @dynsql = ISNULL(@dynsql + ',','') + QUOTENAME(col) FROM #tempi 
UNPIVOT(nav FOR col IN (nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5)) AS unpvt
WHERE  nav1 = 'Grand Total:' AND nav>0

IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
    SET @dynsql = 'SELECT ' + @dynsql + ' FROM #tempi'
    EXEC(@dynsql)
    END

DROP TABLE #tempi
```

Or if you can't use `UNPIVOT`...

```
DECLARE @dynsql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @dynsql = CASE WHEN nav2>0 THEN ',nav2' ELSE '' END + 
                 CASE WHEN nav3>0 THEN ',nav3' ELSE '' END +
                 CASE WHEN nav4>0 THEN ',nav4' ELSE '' END +
                 CASE WHEN nav5>0 THEN ',nav5' ELSE '' END
FROM #tempi 
WHERE  nav1 = 'Grand Total:'

IF(LEN(@dynsql) > 0)
    BEGIN
    SET @dynsql = STUFF(@dynsql,1,1,'SELECT ') + ' FROM #tempi'
    EXEC(@dynsql)
    END
```

Comment: hi martin , i am getting an error..Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'. , i just copied your code and executed in sql..

Comment: @navbingo - Are you on SQL Server 2000 or something?

Comment: Looks like the database you are running it against in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode then.

Comment: this is the info i got it from about tab in sql server 2008..what should i do now , to get the above code to work

Comment: The version of Management studio is irrelevant. What does `SELECT @@VERSION` say? And `EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel 'YourDatabaseName'`

Comment: select @@version output: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64)   Sep 16 2010 19:43:16   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (VM) .. the next out put value is : The current compatibility level is 80.

Comment: hi martin, i just copied your code and executed in the sql server.. do you want me to change anything in your code..

Comment: The server is running 2008 but the database is in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode then. If you run the script in the context of `tempdb` or any other database running in SQL Server 2008 compatibility mode you should find it works. Is there any particular reason the DB is in 2000 mode?

Comment: @martin -- i checked with tempdb its working fine..i got the result..what should i do to get work in my database..

Comment: martin i need another help from u..its a display issue.. i have modified your query,  CASE WHEN nav3>0 THEN ',nav3' ELSE '' END + (CASE WHEN nav4>0 THEN (IsNull(cast(nav4 / 60 as varchar(24)),'0') + ':' + IsNull(cast(nav4 % 60 as varchar(24)),'0')) END) +  but it showing me incorrect syntax near ":"

Comment: bcoz i want to show the output in hours , hh:mm format .. the above query will show only in total minutes

Comment: its done martin, i dynamically created another table and selected the result set from that table..